# normalize data with KPI value

Tags: normalization, feature-scaling

I have this sample of a dataset that show for each number of ads showed to the user, the number of click and the KPI value (CTR):

```
#volume #click  KPI
20        10    0.5
2          2     1
3          1    0.33
20000        1600  0.08
```

KPI values are calculated as : #click/#volume

we want to pick better ads . The issue is that if we consider the KPI as it is , will will consider ads number 2 is the best, but it is not correct, because ads number 2 has only 2 impressions. Any idea to normalize this?

thanks you

Comment: It is fully correct to select the second ad -- but highly uncertain.  How to balance uncertainty against the estimate is something for you to decide, *subjectively,* based on your risk tolerance.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your response, Yes i totally agree, but in thsi case how should  we treat this problem?

Comment: See [our posts referring to MVAT](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=MAVT), *inter alia,* or take a look at utility theory.